# What is the proper syntax for multiple comparisons?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, while-loop

Is there a proper syntax in Ruby for comparing multiple values against the same variable? For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

y = 15
p 'success' if y == 1 || y == 5 || y == -2 || y == 15132 || y == 3.14159265  || y == 15
```

Can that be written as something along the lines of:

```
y = 15
p 'success' if y == 1,5,-2,15132,3.14159265,15
```

And, if so, would that also apply to `while` loops?

```
y = 15
while y != 1,5,-2,15132,3.14159265,15
y = rand(50)
p y
end
```

Based on my search I'm tending to believe this is either not possible, or it's too obscure for my searches.

I hope it's the second case.

I have already considered an array itteration solution, but it's not as pretty or simple as I'd like.

Comment: The exact same expression rules apply to `if` and `while`. Also, be careful when comparing with floating point numbers - it generally will not yield expected results if either number is the result of a calculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `include?`

```
p 'success' if [1,5,-2,15132,3.14159265,15].include? y
```

Answer (score 3):

```
p 'success' if [1, 5, -2, 15132, 3.14159265, 15].include? y
```

Answer (score 3):

```
case y
when 1, 5, -2, 15132, 3.14159265, 15 then p "success"
end
```

Comment: How is my one? please check :)

Answer (score 1):

For a more general case you can use the any? method with a comparison block; this has the advantage of being usable with operators apart from ==:

```
p 'success' if [1, 5, -2, 15132, 3.14159265, 15].any? { |i| i == y }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [`Array#index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-find_index) :

> Returns the index of the first object in ary such that the object is == to obj.Returns nil if no match is found.

```
p 'success' if [1,5,-2,15132,3.14159265,15].index(y)
```